# Automate tests with Postman and Newman

Tags: postman, newman

Here I run into a concern about using Newman on a test campaign I created in Postman. Indeed in some of my test scenarios I test the upload of a PDF file. Requests that handle upload all return status 201 in Postman as I see fit.

In Newman, however, some of these requests return a 415, as if the format was not supported by the API.

[image]

In Postman, the request header looks like this:

[image]

I do not understand why the API returns the correct status (201) in Postman and not in Newman (415). My environment is [Ubuntu 20.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_20.04_LTS_(Focal_Fossa)) (Focal Fossa).

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70875619/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you export your collection, the path of the file you are uploading may change depending on where that file sits on your local machine. So you need to know in advance the path of that file in the container and set it to that path.